# convert key value by using regular expression in string

Tags: python, regex

I am a Python beginner.

```
address = "https://address/#{property_id}/#{unit_id}"

data = {'property_id': "1", 'unit_id': "2"}

result = func(address, data)   # "https://address/1/2"
```

What should go inside some_func?
I don't know whether to use regular expression or simply replace.
address and data can be extended.

```
def func(address, data):
    values = re.findall('#{.*?}', address)
    for value in values:
        data_key = re.search('#{(.*?)}', value, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
        address = address.replace(value, data[data_key])
    return address
```

I have solution, but I guess there's better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a callback.

```py
return re.sub('#{(.*?)}', lambda m: data[m.group(1)], address)
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BCoMwDIbvfYpQD22HKG43YexBxhh1rVOYbYnpQcRnd3XzsMNySf7w/X8SJuq8O61rPwSPBGiZNgbtOMIZeEcUxros91WZzQF9sEjTvTdLktH1tI2cMaNJJ88sfhBRA694DmLnNn3kS4JtC210D7kn57DZVc0gFVqK6FIrxthIkc2yOFzUInJ46aExGob6g1@H4ok@BlmpWw57kmIstfii9MufCyxg70h@EbWubw)